# Would it make technical sense to model its two known subelements separately (CLV example)?

Tags: statistics, ensemble-modeling, variance

Let's assume Customer Lifetime Value (CLV) is defined as `average basket` x `frequency`.

Option A is to build model predicting CLV for each customer.

Option B is to model customer's basket size and frequency, each via separate models and multiply the results at the end.

Is there any mathematical reason why one would select B over A? E.g. would option B  reduce variance of the CLV because it is an ensemble of two models?